# How can I define a phrase that will be replaced with another phrase in c++?

Tags: c++, text

I want to essentially do #define rNum (rand() % 10 + 1)

That is, anywhere in the program the sequence rNum is found it is replaced with the second sequence.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. `#define` is available in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer already, just go ahead and give it a try!

Note that rNum will not be replaced inside of strings, which is usually what you want.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include  <stdlib.h>
#define rNum  (rand() % 10 + 1)
using namespace std;
main() {
  int r;
  r = rNum;
  cout << "Calling rNum sets r to " << r << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

% g++ main.cpp

% a.out

r is 4

%